# Am I short on pc memory, or found a blob size limitation?

Tags: memory, blob, plone

Working on Plone project - thinking I have a pc memory problem, or a blob size limitation.

Project is to create folders for database of airports worldwide, and am only up to P's

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 134, in publish
  Module Zope2.App.startup, line 301, in commit
  Module transaction._manager, line 89, in commit
  Module transaction._transaction, line 329, in commit
  Module transaction._transaction, line 443, in _commitResources
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 562, in commit
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 1185, in _commit_savepoint
  Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 939, in store
  Module ZEO.TransactionBuffer, line 88, in store
MemoryError
```

Using XP machine - data.fs is at 59,357,077KB

Any suggestions, or am I moving from ol' faithful to a bigger machine running Windows 7

Comment: You have hit the per-process memory limit; 2GB on 32-bit Windows systems. This has nothing to do with blob size limits. Most likely you have your ZODB object count to high or are not storing data in a blob but in persistent objects instead.

Comment: Martijn's answer has given me a direction - but how to get over the persistent objects (2Gb memory limit) when I'm only up to the R's in airports. Any design principles or tutorial links would be appreciated.

Comment: Went to 64-bit Windows 7 Professional - have now completed the task of adding all airports within a Plone and look forward to populating the folders.